# Advanced image skewing in JavaScript, fill polygon with image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, transform, polygon

This is what I want to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3rRl.png

The problem with the transform() function is that it keeps the ratio between the sides of the image and cant skew the corners independently.

This is what I have in mind:

```
function draw(a,b,c,d,img) {
    //witchcraft goes here
}
```

where a,b,c,d are the corners and img is the image. The function draws the image in the polygon that the corners create.

Comment: can you post what you have tried? have you looked at CSS 3 transformations?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z1eq3kst/


I've played around with the transform parameters and there's no way (to my knowledge) to manipulate rectangles so that the sides break their parallel relationship.


I will look into CSS 3 transformations

Comment: This is basically what 3D renderers do. Maybe you could look into WebGL?